# upload image to webserver via ajax, and insert given filename into database

Tags: php, sql, ajax

Im currently working on a project that requires the following.

- I need to be able to upload an image (further scope for multiple
  images)
- To an area of a webserver, rename the name of the uploaded images to
  what I want them to be (i.e a specific string that I state with say
  incrememnts on _1 _2 for multiple images e.t.c)
- Done via ajax, as I do not want page reloads.
- Add the returned file name/s into a db.

I have done image uploads before with php, however using the rand to generate a name and return it via post, but not via ajax, Ive done all the bits above before seperately, but not all to gether...

Ive done a quick google search, and none of them seem to work the way that I want them to.

I liked the working of this http://www.zurb.com/playground/ajax_upload but I cant for the life of me get it to work.

Thanks :)

Comment: Try http://www.uploadify.com/

Comment: I want to learn how to do this, not use a pre-built thing that i have to hack apart to get to work the way I want to. Thanks anyway.

Comment: be side Aamir Mahmood's anwser there is no other easy way to do it.. or you need to make a flash file thats posting.. and uploadfy does everything you want to do..

Comment: Then how does facebook do it? That doesnt use flash (for maximum cross browser compat') - or iframes... There are ways to do it, they are built for purpose, hence my request.

Comment: Thank you @Tricker for supporting the view. I also heard php 5.4 is very friendly to file upload and their progress bars ...

Comment: @GraemeLeighfield I wanted to see how GMAIL file attachment works, and i did right click on attach file word and it was in flash. Yes there are tricks

Comment: i will not comment on how facebook done that, as they have modified their database alot and even the php pages are precompiled and hell lot of stuff

Comment: As for progress bars, I heard (but not tested) that using the apache webserver, this is only possible by installing another apache module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, an Upload using AJAX only is not possible. However, there is some kind of workaround for this. You can use a normal file upload (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php for details). Your browser will then try to display the response of the POST you just did. Therefore, you need to point the frame target of your form to a new invisible iframe, so your page content doesnt get changed. You can use the response to the POST to send new javascript code to the browser which for example can display some feedback for the user or display the image you just uploaded. The prototype library ( http://www.prototypejs.org/ )  will help you on some of these tasks.

The link above will also give you hints about how to rename the file, store it on your web server, or even store it in the db. The latter method is not recommended.

Comment: It is possible without iframes. The link i posted in my original post doesnt use Iframes...

Comment: Dear @GraemeLeighfield go to this http://www.zurb.com/javascripts/plugins/ajaxupload.js and go to line 484 it is creating iframe in JS

Comment: kinldy see it again, IE6 word is to tell that name of iframe needed to be unique, right above at on line 489  you will see SAFARI

Comment: Aamir, you are clearly not understanding my needs. Please do not bloat my question any further.

Comment: i am here for help, but you have to understand you can do this only by iFrames or flash there is no other way around. I will not post any more comment here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a concept not the actual code, and i have done this without any issue

1. Create a form for file upload.
2. Create an iFrame on page (hidden, height width 1px) so it is not visible on page
3. Set Upload form target to that frame so when you submit data it will load page in iframe
4. create your own upload file receiving script, and it will have the sessions and other variables
5. the file wihch will receive the image, will store that and update the database
6. on the page where you have upload form, add a script to iframe onPageLoad something, so when that iFrame get content it will trigger a JS, by this JS you can call another ajax call to get uploaded image and display that on your page.

if you are jQuery expert you can create your own plugin with this concept.

Please let me know if you have questions

Comment: IFrames thats like... so old? Theres no need to use them. You can set the image to load from the ajax response...